# how to save and retrieve json array to user default in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, swifty-json, userdefaults

I want to save the response json array and retrieve the json array using userdefault,until now I can only display all json arrays in func fetchdata(), when I try retrieve in viewdidLoad I only get one response json array.
I want to get all the response json arrays in viewdidLoad.
how to achieve it?

here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
        let tabledata = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "id") // here i retrieve data and only get one response
        print("table:\(tabledata)")
    }
    func fetchData(){
        Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {  
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                for item in json.array!{
                    let address = item["address"]["city"].string
                    let id = item["id"].stringValue
                    let userName = item["username"].string
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(id, forKey: "id")
                    let tabledata = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "id") // here i retrieve data and get all response for id
                    print("table:\(tabledata)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I retrieve in view didLoad I only get response:

```
table:Optional(10)
```

When I retrive inside fetchData func, I get all response:

```
table:Optional(1)
table:Optional(2)
table:Optional(3)
table:Optional(4)
table:Optional(5)
table:Optional(6)
table:Optional(7)
table:Optional(8)
table:Optional(9)
table:Optional(10)
```

I want to get all responses like in fetchData func for viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Comment: First of all, you shouldn’t save it to `UserDefaults`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all id in `UserDefaults` as like below.

```
func fetchData(){
    Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json)

            let ids = json.arrayValue.map { $0["id"].stringValue }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(ids, forKey: "id")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can access all ids as like below. wherever you want to use.

```
guard let ids = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "id") else {
       print(ids)
       return
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you doing is storing your data in user default in loop with same key. so every time loop is run your old value will be replace with new one.
that's why when you read your data you will always get last value from of your json response.

try to store value outside of you loop and store `NSArray`typed value in user default.

check below code:

```
let json = JSON(value)
let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
UserDefaults.standard.set(json.array!, forKey: "yourkey")
```

Read your value from `UserDefaults`

```
if userDefault.object(forKey: "yourkey") != nil {
       if let array = yourkey.object(forKey: "aa") as? NSArray {
               print(array) 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the value for key `id` is an integer, not a string, note the missing double quotes.

Second of all in `viewDidLoad` check if the data is already saved and fetch it only if it's not.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let tabledata = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "id") as? [Int] else {
       fetchData()
       return
    }
    print("table:\(tabledata)")
}
```

The problem occurs because you are overwriting the value in `UserDefaults` inside the loop as you are saving the value always for the same key.

Create a temporary array and save the array **once after the loop**

```
func fetchData(){
    Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {  
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            var idArray = [Int]()
            for item in json.array!{
                let address = item["address"]["city"].string
                let id = item["id"].intValue
                idArray.append(id)
                let userName = item["username"].string
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(idArray, forKey: "id")
            print("table:\(idArray)")

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In Swift 4+ it's highly recommended to drop `SwiftyJSON` and any other third-party JSON parsing library in favor of the `Codable` protocol.